# Displaying full years worth of data when part way through

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to display a full years worth of data when only part way through the year and it has been requested to display these future months of the year as 0.

I do not want to add these further months manually post query as when we enter March, March will start displaying data.

My query:

```
   SELECT
   FORMAT(a.CreatedDateTime, 'MMM') AS 'month', 
   SUM(b.NewContactCount) AS 'new_total', 
   SUM(b.TotalContactCount) AS 'all_total' 
   FROM database.dbo.ImportBatch a 
   LEFT JOIN ImportBatch_File b ON a.id = b.BatchID 
   WHERE a.CreatedDateTime >= CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/01/01' 
   GROUP BY FORMAT(a.CreatedDateTime, 'MMM'), MONTH(a.CreatedDateTime) 
   ORDER BY MONTH(a.CreatedDateTime)
```

My results:

```
    month     new_total   all_total
 1  Jan       337         1000
 2  Feb       146         497
```

My desired outcome:

```
    month     new_total   all_total
 1  Jan       337         1000
 2  Feb       146         497
 3  Mar       0           0
 4  Apr       0           0
 5  May       0           0
 6  Jun       0           0
 7  Jul       0           0
 8  Aug       0           0
 9  Sep       0           0
10  Oct       0           0
11  Nov       0           0
12  Dec       0           0
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Do you have a calendar table? If not, then invest in one; you'll find this task much easier then.

Comment: I think a recursive cte would also do well here - build a small temp table using DATEADD in the CTE, and then join on the table. Fill with default values (like 0 for example) and this is an easy task

Comment: What data type is `CreatedDateTime`? You're better off comparing against a *datetime* than a *string*